# How to mount not presented in fstab

Tags: bash, mount, volumes

I have a script which produces information regarding missing volumes, but I can't make use output to mount them back. Could you please help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
mountpoints=( $(awk '$1 !~ /^#/ && $2 ~ /^[/]/ {print $2}' /etc/fstab) )
for mount in ${mountpoints[@]}; do
   if ! findmnt "$mount" &> /dev/null; then
      echo "$mount is declared in fstab but not mounted"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Can't you just do `mount "$mount"`?

Comment: Or `mount -a` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `findmnt` command in parameter execution scope -

```
#!/bin/bash
mountpoints=( $(awk '$1 !~ /^#/ && $2 ~ /^[/]/ {print $2}' /etc/fstab) )
for mount in ${mountpoints[@]}; do
if ! $(findmnt "$mount") &> /dev/null; then
  echo "$mount is declared in fstab but not mounted"
fi
done
```